# The average treatment effect and the difference in means

Tags: conditional-expectation, treatment-effect, counterfactuals

Hi I have a question related to the treatment effect.

Recently, I am reading literatures on treatment effect and have a question.

In the literatures, we denote the counterfactual outcomes as $Y_1$ and $Y_0$ where $Y_1$ is for the treated and $Y_0$ is for the untreated.
Then, the observed outcome is $Y=W\cdot Y_1+(1-W)\cdot Y_0$ where $W$ is the indicator of the treatment.

Here, my first question is whether or not $E(Y_1|W=1)$ and $E(Y|W=1)$ are different?

Second, I found an equation that is as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(Y|W=1)-E(Y|W=0) &= E(Y_1-Y_0)\\
&+\{E(Y_1|W=1)-E(Y_1|W=0)\}P(W=0)\\
&+\{E(Y_0|W=1)-E(Y_0|W=0)\}P(W=1)
\end{aligned}
$$
where P() is the probability function.
But, I can't derive the equation.

Please, Help Me!
Thank you for your time spent to read this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, we have
$$E(Y | W = 1) = E(W\cdot Y_1 + (1 - W) \cdot Y_0 | W = 1) = E(Y_1 | W = 1)$$
where the last equality follows by the fact that we are allowed to plug in the conditioned value of $W$ when evaluating the conditional expectation, so yes, they are equal. Of course, a similar argument shows that $E(Y | W = 0) = E(Y_0 | W = 0)$. I end up using both of these facts below:

To answer your second question, it seems the expression you wrote down is off by a negative sign. To get the correct expression, the only real trick is to use the [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) prudently and to do some light algebra afterwards:

$$
\begin{aligned}
E(Y_1) &= E(Y_1 | W = 1)P(W = 1) + E(Y_1 | W = 0) P(W = 0)\\
&= E(Y_1 | W = 1)[1 - P(W = 0)] + E(Y_1 | W = 0) P(W = 0)\\
&= E(Y_1 | W = 1) - \{E(Y_1 | W = 1) - E(Y_1 | W = 0)\} P(W = 0)\\
&= E(Y | W = 1) - \{E(Y_1 | W = 1) - E(Y_1 | W = 0)\} P(W = 0)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
E(Y_0) &= E(Y_0 | W = 1)P(W = 1) + E(Y_0 | W = 0) P(W = 0)\\
&= E(Y_0 | W = 1)P(W = 1) + E(Y_0 | W = 0) [1 - P(W = 1)]\\
&= E(Y_0 | W = 0) + \{E(Y_0 | W = 1) - E(Y_0 | W = 0)\} P(W = 1)\\
&= E(Y | W = 0) + \{E(Y_0 | W = 1) - E(Y_0 | W = 0)\} P(W = 1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, adding these two equalities together and rearranging, we get

$$
\begin{aligned}
E(Y|W=1)-E(Y|W=0) &= E(Y_1-Y_0)\\
&+\{E(Y_1|W=1)-E(Y_1|W=0)\}P(W=0)\\
&-\{E(Y_0|W=1)-E(Y_0|W=0)\}P(W=1)
\end{aligned}
$$